# Python/Pandas: Apply replacement only when string.startswith a specific string

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Using pandas to read an excel file.
The following code is working fine for one column:

```
data["ProtocolTCP"] = data["ProtocolTCP"].str.replace("tcp-", "tcp ")
```

However, I discovered some cells have the value in the middle of the string and do not want to change those.

How can I just apply the same command to just those string that startswith "tcp-" only?

I think a "lambda" command would work but have a hard time figuring it out. Or perhaps there is a better option than lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `^`

```
data["ProtocolTCP"] = data["ProtocolTCP"].str.replace("^tcp-", "tcp ")
```

Comment: Doh! I knew I was over-engineering it :-), so simple!!! Thank you @YOBEN_S!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where()` which performs better than a lambda I think:

```
data["ProtocolTCP"] = np.where(data["ProtocolTCP"].startswith("tcp-"),data["ProtocolTCP"].str.replace("tcp-","tcp "),data["ProtocolTCP"])
```

Another option using list comprehension:

```
data["ProtocolTCP"] = [x.replace("tcp-","tcp ") if x.startswith("tcp-") for x in data["ProtocolTCP"].values]
```

Comment: Thank you @Celius Stingher, but went with the first option due its simplicity.